# How to show hours and minutes in the time slider on CartoDB?

Tags: carto

CartoDB automatically display only days and months on my custom map. However, I would like to show the following format (included in my data): dd-mm hh-mm.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function main() {      
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoomControl: true,
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 7
  });

  L.tileLayer('URL', {
  }).addTo(map);

      cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      type: "torque",
      order: 1,
      options: {
        table_name: "table_name",
        user_name: "",
       tile_style: $('#cartocss_template').html()
        }
    }).done(function(layer) {
      map.addLayer(layer);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using createVis you can get the `time_slider` element and format it accordingly:

```
 cartodb.createVis('map', 'viz.json')
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
      slider.formatter(function(d) {
        return  d.getUTCMonth()+"-"+ d.getUTCDay() + " "+ d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes();
      })
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! So, it's impossible to configure with createLayer? Because I included a lot of elements directly in my code (custom basemap, carto_css template, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It could be done also with createLayer. Check this example

http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/3f8662160e37d3741082

This is the important part:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map,  {
          type: 'torque',
          order: 1,
          options: {
            query: "SQL",
            user_name:'USERNAME',
            cartocss: "CartoCSS"
          }
    },{})
        .done(function(layer) {
          var slider = map.viz.timeSlider;
          slider.formatter(function(d) {
            return d.getUTCFullYear() + "/" + d.getUTCMonth() + "/"+ d.getUTCDate() + " "+d.getUTCHours()+":"+d.getUTCMinutes()+":"+d.getUTCSeconds();
          })
        }).addTo(map);
```